# how to define type for hateoas links?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Let's take following Rest response,

```
{
   id: 123,
   name : "test",
   addressId : 4
   _links : {
       self : {
                href : "xyz",
                method : "GET"
             },
        address : {
                href : "xyz/address/4",
                method : "GET"
             }
   }
}
```

Is there anyway to define type for `"_links"` here? what i can imagine is i can define something like,

```
interface HateoasUrl {
    href : string;
    method : string; 
}

interface HateoasKeyValuePair{
      [key: string] : HateoasUrl;
}
```

but somehow it doesn't seems to be correct because there will be multiple key values in the `_links`. But this type says there can be only one key value. So how can i define type for an object which can have more than one attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but I interpret this question as: "how can I model a HAL document with typescript?". I'm assuming HAL, because you use the `_links` property, even though HAL doesn't specify a `method` property on links.

I'd do this somewhat like this:

```
interface HalLink {
  href: string;
  type: string;
}

interface HalLinks {
   [s: string]: HalLink | HalLink[];
}
```

Here we have a single link interface, and another type representing the `_links` object. Each item in the `_links` object can either be a single HAL link, or an array of HAL links.

Comment: Why using `interface` instead of `class` ?

Comment: @Stephane that question makes a lot of sense to just search on stackoverflow. It must have been answered quite a few times.